# Access denied for user 'Admin'@'localhost in phpmyadmin

Tags: java

I get the below error

```
Access denied for user 'Admin'@'localhost (using password: YES)
```

Every time I try to connect from java code,
I have created a new user and granted full permission but I still get the same error.

below is the code used to connect from java

```
String userName = "svp01m";
String password = "svp01m";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/project";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);
```

the error message

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' (using password: YES  
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1073)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:943)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:4113)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1308)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2336)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2369)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2153)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:792)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:381)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:305)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at CourseWork.TestFrame2.checkDatabase(TestFrame2.java:169)
at CourseWork.TestFrame2.main(TestFrame2.java:30)

Cannot connect to database server
```

Comment: localhost is not a port, it's a network address (127.0.0.1)

Comment: I am using apache tomacat.. I enter local on the browser and click phpmyadmin.. the port is 8080 i guess

Comment: This `jdbc:mysql://localhost/project` should be `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project`.

Comment: Isn't the port optional? The port 3306 is the default port for MySQL...

Comment: yes.. i tried with jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/project.. it gave the same error

Comment: Which IDE are you using (NetBeans, Eclipse)? You may have forgotten to add the library (jar) of your MySql JDBC Driver **to your project**. Check it out.

Comment: I am using eclispe JUNO and I have added the JAR mysql-connector-java-5.1.21-bin to the project

Comment: Does that library contain this class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`?

Comment: yes the library contains the class ...

Comment: I have also added the error message above

Comment: Are you sure about *userName*, *password* and *database*?

Comment: Yes.. I can share the screenshot of the privileges of these as well

Comment: check the result of **select user, host from mysql.user;**

Comment: The results are host "svp01m" and host "%"

Comment: Are you really running the code you posted? You are trying to connect db with an user `svp01m` but getting an error saying `admin@localhost could not connect` Why admin?? that is very weird.

Comment: yesI am using the username svp01m but  it's strange.. the error always says admin@localhost could not connect...

Comment: I am Still not able to figure out where is the problem :(

Comment: The WampServer Version is  2.2, Jdk version is jdk1.7.0_05, Jre version is 7. eclispse Juno is the IDE.. Is there a compatibility issue ?

Comment: any other ideas anybody please ??

Comment: @Srikanth Hint: Update your question with these new details.

Comment: One thing I Noticed is that the code works when I try to connect from client to database... however when i Connect from client>>web Service and webservice >>database it fails.. Is there other way to connect to the database from webservice